# Remove duplicate entry of column from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to remove all duplicates from the query to return distinct rows of records...

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT (rme.RoleMappingEmployeeKey) AS role_key_one,
    me.EmpSAPID AS emp_sap_id,
    me.SrKey AS emp_sr_key,
    CONCAT(me.EmpFirstName,' ',me.EmpLastName) AS emp_name,
    rm.RoleName AS emp_role_name,
    rm.SubmittedDate AS emp_role_given_date,
    ms.SiteName AS site_name,
    hd.HRDeptName AS dept_name,
    hsd.HRSDName AS sub_dept_name,
    mc2.ClientName AS client_name,
    mb.BusinessTypeName AS bus_type,
    mc3.CompName AS comp_name,
    hem.SeparationDate AS lwd
FROM 
    dbo.RoleMappingEmployee rme
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterEmp me ON me.SrKey = rme.SrKey
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterCountry mc ON (mc.CountryKey = rme.CountryKey OR mc.CountryKey = me.CountryKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.RoleMaster rm ON rm.RoleKey = rme.RoleKey
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.HRMasterEmployeeMain hem ON (hem.SrKey = me.SrKey AND hem.EmployeeStatus=10)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.HRMapping_SubDept_SBand_Desig_SubFunction hsdsdsf ON hsdsdsf.HRSubDeptBDSbKey = hem.HRSubDeptBDSbKey
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.HRMasterSubDepartment hsd ON (hsd.HRSDKey = rme.SubDeptKey OR hsd.HRSDKey = hsdsdsf.HRSDKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.HRMasterDepartment hd ON ( hd.HRDeptKey = rme.DeptKey OR hd.HRDeptKey = hsd.HRDeptKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterSite ms ON (ms.SiteKey = rme.SiteKey OR ms.SiteKey = me.SiteKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterClient mc2 ON (mc2.ClientKey = rme.ClientKey OR mc2.ClientKey = hd.ClientKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterBusiness mb ON (mb.BusinessTypeKey = rme.BusinessTypeKey OR mb.BusinessTypeKey = hd.BusinessTypeKey)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.MasterComp mc3 ON (mc3.CompKey = rme.CompKey OR mc3.CountryKey = mc.CountryKey)
WHERE
    me.IsActive = 0
ORDER BY
    rme.RoleMappingEmployeeKey DESC
```

This query returns a result as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Check the value highlighted below]

the RoleMappingEmployeeKey AS role_key_one, is repeated though i have mentioned the keyword `DISTINCT` for the column in the query...

Comment: `DISTINCT` works on all values in the row, not just the first. Did you search for how to remove duplicates? This sort of question has been asked many, many, many times before.

Comment: That first left joins executes as a regular inner join. Move where clause condition to on clause to get true left join behavior.

Comment: i had seen using the `MIN` function as an alternative but didnt work either

Comment: when i added the where clause to the first left join i get 20x the rows as i am getting now...

Comment: I agree with HoneyBadger. Try distinct by adding / removing the columns you required and compare the result.

Comment: well i need all of the columns that i have there....i did it from the `front` end after receiving the data which returns a multi-dimensional unique array...but i would like to know the options to do the same from the `sql` side of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**

if DISTINCT "doesn't work" it means that there **IS** a difference between "repeated" columns. So, with "duplicates removal" you will lose something - the difference I mentioned above. But... if you do not care about this difference, you could use something like this:

```
WITH dedup as
(
    SELECT 
        (rme.RoleMappingEmployeeKey) AS role_key_one,
        row_number() over (partition by rme.RoleMappingEmployeeKey order by rm.SubmittedDate) [role_key_one_rank],
        me.EmpSAPID AS emp_sap_id,
        me.SrKey AS emp_sr_key,
        CONCAT(me.EmpFirstName,' ',me.EmpLastName) AS emp_name,
        rm.RoleName AS emp_role_name,
        rm.SubmittedDate AS emp_role_given_date,
        ms.SiteName AS site_name,
        hd.HRDeptName AS dept_name,
        hsd.HRSDName AS sub_dept_name,
        mc2.ClientName AS client_name,
        mb.BusinessTypeName AS bus_type,
        mc3.CompName AS comp_name,
        hem.SeparationDate AS lwd
    FROM 
        dbo.RoleMappingEmployee rme
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterEmp me ON me.SrKey = rme.SrKey
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterCountry mc ON (mc.CountryKey = rme.CountryKey OR mc.CountryKey = me.CountryKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.RoleMaster rm ON rm.RoleKey = rme.RoleKey
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.HRMasterEmployeeMain hem ON (hem.SrKey = me.SrKey AND hem.EmployeeStatus=10)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.HRMapping_SubDept_SBand_Desig_SubFunction hsdsdsf ON hsdsdsf.HRSubDeptBDSbKey = hem.HRSubDeptBDSbKey
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.HRMasterSubDepartment hsd ON (hsd.HRSDKey = rme.SubDeptKey OR hsd.HRSDKey = hsdsdsf.HRSDKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.HRMasterDepartment hd ON ( hd.HRDeptKey = rme.DeptKey OR hd.HRDeptKey = hsd.HRDeptKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterSite ms ON (ms.SiteKey = rme.SiteKey OR ms.SiteKey = me.SiteKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterClient mc2 ON (mc2.ClientKey = rme.ClientKey OR mc2.ClientKey = hd.ClientKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterBusiness mb ON (mb.BusinessTypeKey = rme.BusinessTypeKey OR mb.BusinessTypeKey = hd.BusinessTypeKey)
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.MasterComp mc3 ON (mc3.CompKey = rme.CompKey OR mc3.CountryKey = mc.CountryKey)
    WHERE
        me.IsActive = 0
)
select distinct *
from dedup
where [role_key_one_rank] = 1
ORDER BY role_key_one DESC
```

Comment: bingo that worked...removed the duplicates....same as the count in my front-end array after calling the `removeDuplicates` function....
now i got to google the `with` clause....neat little trick there....

Edit: a modern subquery let's say